# What is this Israeli street food dish?

Tags: israel, food-and-drink, identify-this

When I was in Israel a few years back I tried this really great street food. I had gotten the recipe, but now have lost it and don't remember what it was called. It is a cross between a pancake and a bread. The one I had had za'atar, thin sliced tomatoes, and red onion fried into one side and was flipped over. Does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: You wouldn't have a photo of it by any chance?

Comment: Sadly I dont have one

Comment: I have also asked exactly this type of question on cooking.SE with some success. So you might try a parallel question there, or we could migrate it for you if you don't get the right answer after say two weeks.

Comment: I asked it on cooking SE too. I am having more luck here, it looks like.

Comment: Do you remember the city/street that you've eaten it?

Comment: I believe it was Tzvat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to track down the dish. It is called [Lahuhe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lahoh).

[image]

Thank you to everyone for trying to help me out.

Comment: There's also [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lahoh). (In Hebrew it's written "לחוח".)

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a variation on פיתה זעתר "Pita Za'atar". It's just a thick focaccia-style Pita with Za'atar (at a minimum)... the local street vendors add other random pizza-style stuff like tomatoes, onions, etc. almost exactly like traditional Neapolitan Pizza. The source of the word "Pizza" is Pita of course... it's exactly the same concept.

[image]

The recipe is pretty simple:

- Pita
- Za'atar
- Other stuff, to taste

Combine and eat. The end.

Comment: looks close, but what I had was cooked like a pancake and the toppings were placed on top before it was flipped and cooked more, so all the stuff was embedded in the food. I don't think it was a pita.

Comment: Either way, looks tasty...

Comment: I think even that basic recipe should also include olive oil. I don't think I've ever heard of a pita with za'atar without olive oil... might be just me.

Answer (score 5):

My guess it's either Druze Pita ([Recipe and photos on YouTube](http://youtu.be/zMzkFCLjCpg?t=5m8s))
or Man'oushe (Lebanese pizza)

[image: Man'oushe]

Comment: It wasn't this. This is made by making a dough first. What I am thinking of is cooked from a batter like pancakes.